# Кодировка, после компиляции

Tags: java, java-ee, utf-8, jar, кодировка

Изучаю Java. Создал проект с помощью Maven.
Делаю вывод на консоль определенной информации на русском + эту же информацию записываю в файл. 
Когда запускаю в ИДЕА, все хорошо, все работает как нужно. Русский текст и в файле и в консоле отображается нормально.
Но когда я компилю в jar, запускаю с консоли виндовс
`java -jar myprogramm.jar`, то в консоль вывод нормально, а в файл записывает такое

> Åëèçàâåòèíñêîå øîññå, 42, 620024 Åêàòåðèíáóðã, Ðîññèÿ

Файл почему-то сохраняется в кодировке windows 1252 (по крайней мере об этом говорит sublime).

настройки мавена

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

Запись в файл делаю через `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(stringDate() + ".txt", true)`
Когда делаю через `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(stringDate() + ".xml"), "UTF-8");`, где принудительно указываю UTF-8 то все хорошо, но в `PrintWriter` нет метода `append`.

Подскажите как выйти с этого?

Позже пробовал добавить в мавен

```
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

файл создается в UTF-8, но русские символы заменились на знаки вопросов ????
Что делать уже не знаю, спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Извиняюсь, а что за формат такой, "ече"?
Возможно, "txt"? И в этом вся проблема?

Comment: Это я случайно написал, в проекте txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вылечил проблему с помощью

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(stringDate() + ".txt", true),"UTF-8");
```

Comment: Значит помогло бы и так: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 или так System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8"); и можно кодировку не отдавать во writer

Comment: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 при компиляции в консоле ИДЕА, было упомянуто, что мол по дефолту будет использовано. А вот System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8"); думаю вряд ли поможет, так как <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding> делает тоже самое, файл стает UTF-8, но в нутри появляются знаки вопросов. Но спасибо, буду проверять и тестить. Думаю найду оптимальный вариант

Comment: Не при сборке, а при запуске я имел введу.